# Azure Data Factory Script Activity does not like the keyword GO

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

If I create a script, e.g.

```
print 'hello'
GO
print 'cats'
GO
```

Then the script errors when I try to run my ADF pipeline:

> Operation on target GreetCatsActivity failed: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Is GO not allowed in scripts? The issue is I need it to run a gigantic script that is autogenerated and has tons of GO statements in it. Part of the script might reference things created earlier in the script so I suspect the GO statements are important to ensure items are created to be used later on.

Could I be doing something wrong or is there another way to handle this?

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL operator, it's used by IDE (like) applications as a batch separator. If you have multiple batches that need to be run as separate batches you separate nodes for each batch.

Comment: GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Comment: Separate ScriptActivities within ADF? There are 134 GO statements in my script. Perhaps they are not all essential though

Comment: Is this script stored in a variable? Or is it any activity's output? (since you have mentioned that the script is auto generated)

Comment: It comes from a tool that generates a table creation script, and puts GO between each statement. So what I've done is removed all of the GO statements and I will see if that works. I've tried to put things that depend on those tables existing into a new ScriptActivity, so perhaps this will solve it (and is the right thing to do). Many thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

Just throught of sharing this as a think this may be helpful .
You can use the a Mapping data flow pipeline to replace the "GO" .
What I tried is on the source side I added the scripts ( a files with the extension .sql , I am assuming you must be gaving something similar  )  which is shared with "GO" above &  I used the FIlter to ger rid of the all the GO's and on the sink I did write back the scripts ( without GO to a blob .

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now I wanted to automate the execution of the command using the Script activity in ADF .

For executing the queries we will use the a Lookup which will read the file which we created in the last step and a for each loop and a Script activity inside that .

My lookup output looks something like

[image]

and so wjem you are setting the scripts activity , please pass dynamic value as i did
[image]

[image]

HTH